# implicit Objective-C entrypoint on updating code to swift 4

Tags: swift, swift4

I am getting following warning on updating my code to swift 4

> *implicit Objective-C entrypoint -[development.ASTodayViewController tableView:heightForHeaderInSection:] is deprecated and will be removed
>   in Swift 4*

How to resolved that ?

I have table delegate method as

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
        heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      return 40.0  
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting this issue in Today Extension?

Comment: No ASTodayViewController is as viewController.

Comment: Add more code to the question.

Comment: You should probably mention that this is a *runtime warning*, not a compile-time one. You must be doing something quite weird to trigger it though, as implementations of `@objc` protocol requirements are inferred to be `@objc`. What backtrace do you get if you set the `SWIFT_DEBUG_IMPLICIT_OBJC_ENTRYPOINT` environment variable to 2? (Edit scheme > Run > Arguments > Environment variables). Does `ASTodayViewController ` conform to `UITableViewDelegate`?

Comment: Yes that class confirms to UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource

Comment: @AashishNagar Okay, could you please show us more context around the declaration of the method as well as the backtrace I asked for above?

Comment: in Swift3 few method of UITableViewDelegate has been renamed. Changing the method name fixed the issue. Thank you Hamish your comment helped in it.

Comment: @AashishNagar No worries! Please *always* show your real code in a question though, as the method you have in your question is correctly named.

Answer (score 10):

**implicit Objective-C entrypoint** mainly refer to the @`objc` inferences that were used implicitly before *Swift 4*.

But ***Swift 4***, doesn't allow these `@objc` implicit inferences.

> Before Swift 4, the compiler made some Swift declarations
>   automatically available to Objective-C. For example, if one subclassed
>   from NSObject, the compiler created Objective-C entry points for all
>   methods in such classes. The mechanism is called @objc inference.
>
> In Swift 4, such automatic @objc inference is deprecated because it is
>   costly to generate all those Objective-C entry points. When “Swift 3
>   @objc Inference” setting is set to “On”, it allows the old code to
>   work. However, it will show deprecation warnings that need to be
>   addressed. It is recommended to “fix” these warnings and switch the
>   setting to “Default”, which is the default for new Swift projects.

If you still want to use it, you can set `Swift 3 @objc Inference` in `Build Settings` to `On`.

[image]

Add some more code to the question so that I can tell you the exact issue.

Comment: This won't fix the warning though. In fact, the warning is only enabled while Swift 3 `@objc` inference is enabled.

Comment: Of course it will show it as the warning. If you switch it off, it will appear as an error. Regarding fixing it, I already told you to add more code. The answer I gave is a bit more generalised one that you can use to debug the issue at a higher level. We can't help you until you show more of your code.

Comment: I'm not the OP; I was just noting that OP must already have the "Swift 3 @objc Inference" flag set to "on" as the warning they're getting is only present when that flag is enabled.

Comment: is this even a answer?